# Reasons for stty -tostop having no effect

Tags: bash, rhel, tty, background-process, stty

I am trying to get a background process to print to the terminal. I haven't seen anything that otherwise indicates there is anything else to do besides `stty -tostop`. Am I missing something? Running RHEL 9.2. `jobs -l` reports:

`Stopped (tty output)    command > /dev/pts/2`

Why does `stty -tostop` not seem to have any effect in alleviating this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had to do the following:

`command < /dev/null &> /dev/pts/0 &` to redirect both stdin and stdout it seems